# understanding ruby on rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, diagram

For me to understand the rails project is not enough to see the model or controller diagrams and how many attributes and actions they're having. I understand more if I know where actions are initialized and how they ended. To describe my thoughts more specifically I'll show some example. Let's take nice open project Railscasts. I chose the Comment controller because it nested inside others controllers then it's a little harder to understand how this works. Here's my picture that helps me to understand it.
[image]

This isn't well composed diagram but fine for me. On this picture you can see where action is started and what's the reaction on action. The action **edit** initiates in views/episodes/show.html.erb, comes to controller's action edit, after that shows the edit form, then go to update action and finally go back to show.html.erb. From this picture you can see that a lot of actions initiate in show.html.erb that belongs to **episode** controller and makes harder to understand how works the comments controller. Now you can easy find place where is action comes.

Here is my questions:

1. Do you think this idea is useful for you, can make your developer's life easier ?
2. Do you know some tool that can make such kind of pictures automatically ?

Comment: Are you intending to make such a tool ?

Comment: for this moment - no, maybe in future if it will demanded

Answer (score 3):

This is quite argumentative, but answering to question 1 :), I have to say that your diagram has a huge  noise/signal ratio. 
Your diagram only talks me about routing which honestly in a mid-sized scenario is not so complicated to need a diagram. And does it pushing a lot of noise (why I need to see the class of a destroy link?)
Rails is a lot about conventions and to be honest I don't feel the routing mechanism to be so complicated to need a diagram. Just my 2 cents.

To Question 2: I often find RubyMine model diagram to be quite useful, but I think you need a more 'dynamic' view of the project.

Comment: like i said, my diagram is not well composed, it could be more clear. But, maybe you missed my point, from model diagram i can't understand how project works and i don't believe that you can. I can build model diagram in my mind just reading the source, it's very easy. Hard things for me is understand how one controller/model interacts with another ones, find where is action initiated, which partitions uses now and some projects can even change main layout dynamically - isn't that embarrassing?

Comment: Anyway, as I said, your question is quite argumentative. But I can say 'I like your diagram' if it makes you happy ;)